# How to create space between to TextField in SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

I have created three text boxes in sapui5. i want to separate those text boxes with spaces. I have tried with `&nbsp` spacing but that hasn't work. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I have to use a space I use `"\u00a0"`.

So e.g.

```
createContent : function(oController) {
    var content = [];

    content.push(new sap.ui.commons.TextField({
        value : "Field1"
    }));
    content.push(new sap.ui.commons.TextView({
        text : "\u00a0"
    }));
    content.push(new sap.ui.commons.TextField({
        value : "Field2"
    }));
    content.push(new sap.ui.commons.TextField({
        value : "Field3"
    }));
    return content;
}
```

will create three TextFields, where the first and second are seperated by one space

Comment: for space it is ok. for break??

Comment: for breaks you should try the sap.ui.commons.layout.VerticalLayout